# DD4T 2.0 XPM Integration

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, web8, iis-and-asp.net

Looking at the classes in the [DD4T.Mvc.ViewModels.XPM](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.MVC/tree/50cc439f89255c3107c9861ad40c55f12dcd85fd/source/DD4T.Mvc/ViewModels/XPM) namespace, I see extensions for many XPM tags to markup regions and fields.

I do not see Extensions for:

1. Page Initalization
2. Base JS includes

Are these available and I am missing them, or are these not yet implemented in DD4T 2.0?

Comment: Having the same problem Chris, trying to find out how the Page Level XPM script is added while using ViewModels